# ¿Cómo aplicar mergeSort a un vector de objetos?

Tags: java, array, object, ordenamiento, atributos

El vector de objetos se compone de puntos, cada punto tiene una coordenada x e y. Teniendo en cuenta que necesito realizar dos ordenamientos, uno utilizando la coordenada X y otro usando la coordenada Y me recomendaron pasar a otro vector la coordenada en cuestión y aplicarle el ordenamiento a ese vector, pero a la vez que se vayan moviendo, ir moviendo el vector de objetos original. Tengo el mergeSort y me funciona, pero aun no logro que me funcione el movimiento de los objetos.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public void merge(double[] array, int start, int mid, int end, Point[] Point){
    // create a temp array
    double[] temp = new double[end - start + 1];
    // tracking vars for intervals and for temp
    int i = start, j = mid + 1, k = 0, cont = 0;
    // traverse both arrays and in each iteration add smaller of both elements int temp
    while(i <= mid && j <= end){
        if(array[i] <= array[j]){
            temp[k] = array[i];
            k++; i++; cont++;
        }else{
            temp[k] = array[j];
            Point tempo = Point[j];  // se supone que aca hace un swap
            Point[cont] = tempo;     // para mover el objeto punto
            k++; j++; cont++;   
        }
    }
    // add elements left in the first interval
    while(i <= mid){
        temp[k] = array[i];
        k++; i++;
    }
    // add elements left in the second interval
    while(j <= end){
        temp[k] = array[j];
        k++; j++;
    }
    // copy temp to original interval
    for(i = start;i <= end;i++){
        array[i] = temp[i - start];
    }
}

// start and end are the starting and ending index of current interval of array
public void mergeSort(double[] array, int start, int end, Point[] Point){
    if(start < end){
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, start, mid, Point);
        mergeSort(array, mid+1, end, Point);
        merge(array, start, mid, end, Point);
    }
}
```

ahora el main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test t = new test();
    Point[] puntos = new Point[10];

    puntos[0] = new Point(5.1, 5.2);
    puntos[1] = new Point(3.3, 4.2);
    puntos[2] = new Point(7.5, 6.5);
    puntos[3] = new Point(4.2, 5.0);
    puntos[4] = new Point(8.3, 7.6);
    puntos[5] = new Point(5.9, 7.0);
    puntos[6] = new Point(6.4, 5.2);
    puntos[7] = new Point(2.6, 3.7);

    double[] coordX = new double[8];

    for(int i = 0;i < coordX.length;i++){
        coordX[i] = puntos[i].getX();
    }

    t.mergeSort(coordX, 0, coordX.length - 1, puntos);

    for(double x : coordX){
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    for(Point p : puntos){
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Obtengo dos salidas, el vector de coord ordenado en X (Funciona) y el vector de puntos ordenado con referencia al vector de coord(No funciona)

```
2.6
3.3
4.2
5.1
5.9
6.4
7.5
8.3

Point{x=8.3, y=7.6}
Point{x=7.5, y=6.5}
Point{x=2.6, y=3.7}
Point{x=4.2, y=5.0}
Point{x=5.9, y=7.0}
Point{x=6.4, y=5.2}
Point{x=6.4, y=5.2}
Point{x=2.6, y=3.7}
null
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de intentar varias cosas y guiarme con otros metodos de ordenamiento, llegué a la conclusión en que claramente no le estaba aplicando el mergesort al vector de objetos, la solución fue la siguiente:

```
public void merge(double[] array, int start, int mid, int end, Point[] Point){
    // create a temp array
    double[] temp = new double[end - start + 1];
    Point[] tempo = new Point[end - start + 1];   // CREO UN VECTOR AUX DE PUNTOS PARA
                                                  // PARA IR LLENANDO EL VECTOR CON 
                                                  // CADA MOVIMIENTO
    // tracking vars for intervals and for temp
    int i = start, j = mid + 1, k = 0; //cont = 0;
    // traverse both arrays and in each iteration add smaller of both elements int temp
    while(i <= mid && j <= end){
        if(array[i] <= array[j]){
            temp[k] = array[i];
            tempo[k] = Point[i];   // AGREGO EL PUNTO CORRESPONDIENTE AL VECTOR AUX
            k++; i++;
        }else{
            temp[k] = array[j];
            tempo[k] = Point[j];    // AGREGO EL PUNTO CORRESPONDIENTE AL VECTOR AUX
            k++; j++;
        }
    }
    // add elements left in the first interval
    while(i <= mid){
        temp[k] = array[i];
        tempo[k] = Point[i];    // AGREGO EL PUNTO CORRESPONDIENTE AL VECTOR AUX
        k++; i++;
    }
    // add elements left in the second interval
    while(j <= end){
        temp[k] = array[j];
        tempo[k] = Point[j];      // AGREGO EL PUNTO CORRESPONDIENTE AL VECTOR AUX
        k++; j++;
    }
    // copy temp & tempo to original interval
    for(i = start;i <= end;i++){
        array[i] = temp[i - start];
    }
    for(i = start;i <= end;i++){
        Point[i] = tempo[i - start];
    }
}
```